# Vanilla Masker and jQuery on keyup issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Vanilla Masker](https://github.com/fernandofleury/vanilla-masker) and jQuery to mask a field. A valid phone will be 10 in length (minus the dashes) using this mask `999-999-9999`.

The issue I am facing is that when I type the last digit as a letter, the length count seems to be ten even when it is not registered because only numbers can be entered (any character which is not a number is removed). For example, if I type 888-888-888x, the x will be removed and my code is saying the length has been reached.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qq7aqa9b/)

Answer (score 0):

Checked if the contents of the field are only digits. A modified getPhoneLength() as follows:

```
function getPhoneLength() {
    var onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/.test($("#phone").val().replace(/[_-]/g, ''));
    if ($("#phone").val().replace(/[_-]/g, '').length == 10 && onlyNumbers) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Updated [jsFiddke](https://jsfiddle.net/qq7aqa9b/1/)